# Changing variables from different classes

Tags: java, colors

I am trying to have a button call a method in another class to update the color of something, however it is not functioning as I expect it to. The issue is that the color is changed once but never changed again.

This is the file where the changing happens:

```
public class Status
{
    //initial conditions
    Color pedLightColor = Color.RED;
    Color warnLightsColor = Color.GREEN;
    Boolean GatesUp= true;
    Color drawbridgeColor = Color.green;    
    public Status()
    {       
    }

    public Color getPedestrianStatus()
    {
       return pedLightColor;
    }

    public void setPedestrianColor(Color c)
    {
        if(c.equals(Color.RED))
        {
           pedLightColor=Color.green;
           System.out.println("Pedestrian Light color changed to " + pedLightColor);
        }
        else
        {
               pedLightColor=Color.red;
               System.out.println("Pedestrian Light color changed to " + pedLightColor);
        }
    }
}
```

and it is called as follows:

```
pedButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
           System.out.println("Control Unit/Pedestrian Button Clicked");
           Status status = new Status();
           status.setPedestrianColor(status.getPedestrianStatus());
           System.out.println(status.getPedestrianStatus());
        }
});
```

Currently I believe that I am changing the color by calling the setPedestrianColor() method with the current color as the argument. However I am not sure why once you press the button a second time the color should be green so it should change back to red but this is not the case. Any suggestions for where I am going wrong are appreciated.

Comment: Why is `setPedestrianColor()` not using its argument to set the color, but the opposite instead? Maybe you should call it `togglePedestrianColor()` and remove its argument, or make it set the color to the argument, don't you think?

Comment: It's probably because you are creating new Status object when you want to set new color, and another one when you want to get color.

Comment: As an aside, is Color.red and Color.RED the same thing?

Comment: Would recommend changing the name of `setPedestrianColor()`. Based on the name one would expect that the function would set the pedestrian's color to the color input, however it sets it to the opposite color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Status` object needs to be global or instantiated in a different way. The color is being changed and then the object is being thrown away after every time `actionPerformed` is called. So it never really changes from Red to Green.

Comment: Yes that was it. After changing the status object to global it functioned as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is because you create a brand new `Status` object each time you press the button.

```
Status status = new Status();
```

Consider declaring `status` as a field initializing it only ones.